# Multiple lines in a menu item or picker

Tags: swiftui

I've started using SwiftUI and trying to convert an application that I've created with Jetpack Compose to iOS, but I've run into a problem with menus (or picker if that's easier).

What I want to do is to be able to create items that has multi-lines and different font size for the two lines. But I can't make it work, only the first line is visible

I've tried something like:

```
Picker("Select menu item", selection: $selectedItem) {
   ForEach(0..<items.count) {
        VStack  {
            Text("Menu item 1").fontWeight(.bold) // Only this text is shown
            Text("Description")
        }
   }
}
```

I've also tried with

```
Menu("Options") {
     VStack  {
        Text("Menu item 1").fontWeight(.bold) // Only this text is shown
        Text("Description")
     }
}
```

What I want it to look like is something like:
[image]

I've spent many hours trying to find an example of something like this. Is this possible to do in SwiftUI? If not, what control should you suggest to use instead?

Comment: You have to create it yourself. Maybe a `ZStack` or using UIKit to create an over the context sheet/popover

Comment: I see. Have you got ideas what I should search for to see an example of something similar? As said, new to iOS development. I couldn't find anything similar when searching for it previously.

Comment: I have plenty of ideas but this isn’t the place for free code. Give it a try and we can help with the kinks.

Comment: I didn't want free code, I wanted a some more hints in the right direction, since I'm totally new to swiftui and UIKit. :)

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Answer (score 5):

If you are attempting to add something like below, then just use the `content` closure of `Button`. Note that this only applies to menu items and does not add picker checkmark functionality. You could write this yourself with an `HStack` instead.

[image]

```swift
Menu("HI") {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Text(temperatureType.localizedDescription)
        Text(formatTemperature(sensor.temperature, to: 
    temperatureType.toUnitTemperature()))
    }
}
```

Then you can add any of the modifiers you would like.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it's worth noting that doing it this way prevents `Picker`'s automatic addition of checkmarks to indicate the selected item.

Comment: @shauneba. Thanks for noting that this is only for menu items