# SwiftUI Picker in Menu

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, swiftui-picker, swiftui-menu

I want to display the selection when using a picker in menu like in the reminders app for Sort By and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it.

This is what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwm2R.jpg

This is my code:

```
private func menuButton() -> some View {
    Menu {
        Menu {
            Picker(selection: $group, label: Text("Grouping options")) {
                Text("None").tag(0)
                Text("Type").tag(1)
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Group By", systemImage: "square.grid.3x1.below.line.grid.1x2")
        }
        Menu {
            Picker(selection: $sort, label: Text("Sorting options")) {
                Text("Name").tag(0)
                Text("Priority").tag(1)
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Sort By", systemImage: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
        }
        Divider()
        Button {
            toggleInbox()
        } label: {
            Label(inboxList?.isHidden == false ? "Hide Inbox" : "Show Inbox", systemImage: inboxList?.isHidden == false ? "eye.slash" : "eye")
        }
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle.fill")
            .font(.custom("Button", size: 22))
            .foregroundStyle(.blue, Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Button` as the label for your `Menu` (see [Swiftui: multiple lines in a menu item or picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953972/swiftui-multiple-lines-in-a-menu-item-or-picker)):

```swift
Menu {
    Picker(selection: $sort, label: Text("Sorting options")) {
        Text("Name").tag(0)
        Text("Priority").tag(1)
    }
} label: {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Text("Sort by")
        Text(sort == 0 ? "Name" : "Priority")
        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
    }
}
```

Another hint: you can use `.pickerStyle(.menu)` on your `Picker`, so you don't have to wrap it in a `Menu`.